# Rotation reference point centering problem in as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have the following problem. I have an MovieClip in a holder MC.

I would like to turn the inner MC `X` with 'rotation' parameter, and still keep it in the holder mc to the right and bottom of the holder MC reference point. So after turning it should look like that:

```
+------ 
|X
|
```

rather than

```
 X
+------
|
|
```

anyone can tell me how to do that? Basically a function that takes any X rotated in any degrees through `X.rotation = ...` and puts it back in place in the holder MC.

thanx

Comment: i'd like to help but i miss the point: what is the start position, which one is rotated (and to what angle) and what is the final position - desired and real... imho a picture'd be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way would be for the rotating MC to have the registration point at the center, but it also depends on the shape of your rotating MCs. 

For a complex shape, you could have the rotated MC contained within a circle. The  circumference of the circle would be created by the rotation of the rotating mc's outermost point. The registration point of your circle therefore becoming the rotating mc's registration point.

The way to handle this implementation depends on your developing environment, with the Flash IDE , it's pretty straighforward...

Answer (score 0):

Say you want to rotate mc_child inside mc_parent by 0.5.

```
tempSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
tempSprite.x = mc_child.x;
tempSprite.y = mc_child.y;
mc_parent.addChild(tempSprite);

mc_child.rotation += 0.5;

addChild(mc_child);
```

If the change of parent is a problem, You may use a matrix transform.

Answer (score 0):

A function like this?

```
function getPositionOffset(rotation:Number, origin:Point):Point
{
    var radVal:Number= Math.PI * rotation / 180;

    var offsetX:Number = origin.x - origin.x * Math.cos(radVal)
        + origin.y * Math.sin(radVal);
    var offsetY:Number = origin.y - origin.x * Math.sin(radVal)
        - origin.y * Math.cos(radVal);

    return new Point(offsetX, offsetY);
}
```

Then you rotate the object like so:

```
// original position before any rotation
var originalX:Number = obj.x;
var originalY:Number = obj.y;

// let's say origin for a 100x100 object is 50,50
var origin:Point = new Point(50, 50);

// rotation: 45
var pt:Point = getPositionOffset(45, origin);

obj.rotation = 45;

obj.x = Math.floor(originalX + pt.x);
obj.y = Math.floor(originalY + pt.y);
```

Well, that's the general idea. You could improve on this by not requiring the pre-rotation `originalX` and `originalY` values and have them computed instead (using current rotation and position).